# Why is Identity Seed showing the wrong value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have set the seed value from 1 to 100 using the below command, but SQL Server still shows 1 as an Identity Seed value, It should be.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName, RESEED, 100);
```

When I run this `SELECT IDENT_SEED('TableName')` , it still shows 1, In design also it is showing 1.

When I insert the records the tables, its getting inserted properly, I mean after 100 only.

**SSMS Version:** 18.4

[image: Design]

Comment: @Larnu but command also showing the wrong value, it should show 100, not 1

Comment: You changed the seed counter, *not* the table's schema

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so is this not the right approach? which I have done? So What shall we do? change the counter or change the scheme? How to change the schema if we need to change the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDENT_SEED` *doesn't* return the current seed of the table, what you have is working. From [IDENT_SEED (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-seed-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns the **original seed value** specified when creating an identity column in a table or a view. **Changing the current value of an identity column by using DBCC CHECKIDENT doesn't change the value returned by this function**.

*Emphasis mine.*

If you want to check the current seed, then follow the instructions in `DBCC CHECKIDENT`: `DBCC CHECKIDENT (N'dbo.YourTable', NORESEED);`.

Example:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.IdentID (ID int IDENTITY(1,1));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.IdentID
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
--Returns 1
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IdentID;
GO
--Returns 1
SELECT IDENT_SEED(N'dbo.IdentID') AS IDENTSEED;
GO
--Returns 1 for identity value, as it gives the last used value
DBCC CHECKIDENT (N'dbo.IdentID', NORESEED);
GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT (N'dbo.IdentID', RESEED, 100);
GO
--Returns 1
SELECT IDENT_SEED(N'dbo.IdentID') AS IDENTSEED;
GO
--Returns 100 for identity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT (N'dbo.IdentID', NORESEED);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.IdentID
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
--Returns rows with IDs of 1 and 101
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IdentID;
GO

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.IdentID;
```

Comment: Thank you, it answers my question :)